Best Search Algorithim
In Microsoft Power Bi there are formulas that can be used in visualizations called measures. These measures can be used within the formulas of other measures.
As a result, a measure can have a complex interdependency on another measure. I am looking for the best search algorithm I can give a measure and then use to search the other measures to identify the dependencies.
I have made a visual of what these dependencies can look like: https://i.imgur.com/cgSNmkx.png
Any suggestions on a algorithm I can use?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reachability, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search

If they form a order/you can determine in which direction you should search further when you check whether some measure is the one you are looking for you can check binary search in graphs. If your graph is directed unluckily this problem is PSPACE-complete even if cost of checking whether any measure is your target measure is uniform for all measures. However for undirected tree this problem is solvable in $O(n)$ time, and for general graphs it is solvable within $O(\log n)$ approximation factor polynomially.
Try following papers:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.00805
https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4031373
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S030439751630353X
https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.08207
